# React navigation v4 to v5 issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

So, i am currently on Navigation v4 using SwitchNavigator. I want to migrate to v5 but i can't get it working Switch like. I have 3 stacks, AuthStack(Stack navigator), TabScreens(it's a bottom navigator), Terms(just a screen) and my v4 configuration is this:

```
  const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false, terms) => {
  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Auth: { screen: AuthStack, path: 'auth' },
        App: { screen: TabScreens, path: 'app' },
        Terms: { screen: Terms }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: !signedIn ? !terms ? 'Terms' : 'Auth' : 'App',
        headerMode: 'none',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          gestureEnabled: false
        }
      }
    ))
}
```

So the first time when the Terms screen shows up and press Next, then i automatically navigate to Auth and if i press the android back button then the app closes bacause the Auth stack is the main stack. The same doesn't happen on v5 though. I have an error that `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Auth"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Auth'?`

My in progress v5 configuration is like this:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const Auth = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"SignIn"}>
    <AuthStack.Screen
      name={"SignIn"}
      component={SignIn}
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
)

const TermsStack = createStackNavigator();
const TermsScreen = () => (
  <TermsStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"Terms"}>
    <TermsStack.Screen
      name={"Terms"}
      component={Terms}
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
  </TermsStack.Navigator>
)


const RootScreens = () => {
  const signedIn = mySDK.isAuthorized();
  const terms = myApi.getTerms();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {!signedIn ?
        <>
          {!terms ?
            <TermsScreen />
            :
            <Auth />
          }
        </>
        :
        // <App />
        <Auth />
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default RootScreens;
```

What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I have the same issue can you solve it?

Comment: @AmirFarahani i finally solved it. I will post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

So, i finally managed to get it working. Below is a demo code.

```
import TabScreens from './TabScreens';
        
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const Auth = () => (
<AuthStack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={"LoginMethods"}>
        <AuthStack.Screen
          name={"LoginMethods"}
          component={LoginMethods}
          screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS
          }}
        />
    
        <AuthStack.Screen
          name={"Login"}
          component={Login}
          screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
          }}
        />
    
        <AuthStack.Screen
          name={"SignUp"}
          component={SignUp}
          screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
          }}
        />
    
        <AuthStack.Screen
          name={"ForgotPassword"}
          component={ForgotPassword}
          screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
          }}
        />
    
        <AuthStack.Screen
          name={"ChangePassword"}
          component={ChangePassword}
          screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
          }}
        />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );


const TermsStack = createStackNavigator();
const TermsScreen = () => (
  <TermsStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"Privacy"}>
    <TermsStack.Screen
      name={"Privacy"}
      component={Privacy}
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
      }}
    />
    <TermsStack.Screen
      name={"Terms"}
      component={Terms}
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
      }}
    />
  </TermsStack.Navigator>
);


const RootScreens = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const routeNameRef = React.useRef();

  const signedIn = useSelector(state => state.profile.authorized);
  const showTerms = useSelector(state => state.content.terms);

  //***** Save the initial route name *****/
  React.useEffect(() => {
    routeNameRef.current = signedIn ? 'App' : !showTerms ? 'Terms' : 'Auth';
  }, []);
  //***** Save the initial route name *****/

  const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={ref}
      initialState={initialState}
      onStateChange={(state) => {
        const prevScreen = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentScreen = getActiveRouteName(state);
        if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
          // sendEvent('screen:' + currentScreen, false);
        }
        // Save the current route name for later comparision
        routeNameRef.current = currentScreen;
      }}>
      {
    signedIn ?
        (
            <TabScreens />
        )
        : !showTerms ?
            (
                <TermsScreen />
            )
            :
            (
                <Auth />
            )
}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
```

As you can see here we have implemented what React is calling it, dynamic navigation. We have some values from our redux store that when they change then the Navigation Container dynamically re-renders per case (the inline if-else condition). So for example at the app's first open we show the Terms screen (useSelector(state => state.content.terms) is false) and when we press the button accept terms we dispatch that action with true. Then the app now knows that the showTerms is true but the signIn is still false so it goes to the Login screen. When we press the login button and after the login process with our server completes then we dispatch the signIn variable with true and the app navigates itself into the other screens (the main app's Tabscreens).

Keep in mind that i didn't mention anywhere of navigating to those stacks (Terms, Auth) but only a redux dispatch action. That's because we don't need to navigate to them, a dispatch is the only choice here and if we try to navigate from one stack to another then we will get a red screen.